# how to show the number of characters left in a multiline textbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a multiline textbox which can contain only 500 characters. Now i want to show the user the number of characters left as they are typing into the textbox as is the case when we use twitter.

Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

See [ASP.NET Text Character Counter](http://www.rosshawkins.net/archive/2006/12/04/asp.net-text-counter.html.aspx) by Ross Hawkins.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write some js code.

here is simple snipptet:

```
<html><form name="form1"><input type="text" name="textArea" size="400" onkeyup="document.form1.count_display.value=document.form1.textArea.value.length;"><br/><input type="text" name="count_display"></form></body></html>
```

you can change the calculation to show the characters left, or the already typed count, as you need

Comment: Thanks for the code but the textbox is asp.net control not html control.

Comment: of course. It was only for the sample. you can paste the client events, it will work the same

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create a multiline textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textTextBox" Text='<%# Bind("Text") %>' runat="server" 
CssClass="text     smsTextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" 
MaxLength="500" >
</asp:TextBox>

<p>
   <span id="remaining" class="remaining">500 characters remaining</span> 
   <span id="messages" class="messages">1 message(s)</span>
</p>
```

Now add this to a javascript file or add this to Javascript to the the page the item is being rendered.
Everytime the Document is loaded the script is Run

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (typeof $('.smsTextBox').val() !== "undefined") {
        var $remaining = $('.remaining'),
        $messages = $remaining.next();

        var chars = $('.smsTextBox').val().length,
            messages = Math.ceil(chars / 500),
            remaining = messages * 500 - (chars % (messages * 500) || messages * 500);

        $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
        $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
    }

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $remaining = $('.remaining'),
        $messages = $remaining.next();

    $('.smsTextBox').keyup(function () {
        var chars = this.value.length,
            messages = Math.ceil(chars / 500),
            remaining = messages * 500 - (chars % (messages * 500) || messages * 500);

        $remaining.text(remaining + ' characters remaining');
        $messages.text(messages + ' message(s)');
    });
});

</script>
```

Happy coding :-D